# c++ template double std::complex<double> norm and product

Tags: c++, class, templates, std, norm

i wrote a template class that should work for double and std::complex. as it is suppose to be, all my methods are in the .hpp file. all but one. i had to specialize a method because at some place i have to compute the square of a double or the norm of a std::complex. more explicitly for the "double specialization" (A):

```
double a(2.0);
double b(0.0);
b = a*a;
```

for the "complex specialization" (B):

```
std::complex<double> a(2.0,3.0);
double b(0.0);
b = std::norm(a);
```

my questions are :

- is there a way to avoid theses specializations by using a function that works for both double and complex ? (because the std::norm works only for complex...)
- or the only solution is to cast the double a of the specialization (A) into a complex and then use only the specialization (B) as a general template (working for both double and complex)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can minimise the divergent case by introducing your own function as a square/norm wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
double square_or_norm(T x);

template<>
inline double square_or_norm(double x) { return x * x; }

template <>
inline double square_or_norm(std::complex<double> x) { return norm(x); }
```

Then, use it inside the function which needs it:

```
template <typename T>
T computation(T x) {
  return some_code_with(x, square_or_norm(x));
}
```

Comment: thanks i see your point ! but then i still have a method that is specialized and that has to be in a separate .cpp file...

Comment: @user2110463 It doesn't have to be in a .cpp file. I've marked the specialisations `inline`, so they can be in the header along the rest of your functions.

Comment: @user2110463 that is nearly the *only* benefit of keyword `inline` these days, since the real inlining is left to the compiler/optimizer and it can decide wether to inline or not completely independent of the presence of `inline` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a conforming standard library, there is an overload of `std::norm` for floating point types:

> **26.4.9** Additional overloads [cmplx.over]
>   The following function templates shall have additional overloads:
>       `arg norm
>       conj proj
>       imag real`
>   The additional overloads shall be sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If the argument has type long double, then it is effectively cast to complex.
> 2. Otherwise, if the argument has type double or an integer type, then it is effectively cast to complex<
>      double>.
> 3. Otherwise, if the argument has type float, then it is effectively cast to complex.

This should work (and does on [gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/GzPAXp))

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> c {1.5, -2.0};
    double d = 2.5;

    std::cout << "|c| = " << std::norm(c) << '\n'
              << "|d| = " << std::norm(d) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I'd want to look at the generated code. I've seen std::norm call cabs() [which is really hypot(re,im) ] and square the result inline. Maybe the compiler will skip that overhead when the imag part is zero. I suspect this use of 'cabs' is done to get the benefit of the inf/nan checking that hypot does (e.g. hypot(inf,nan)=inf).  Or, one hopes, the `std::norm(double x)` is actually just `(x*x)` rather than the `std::norm( std::complex(x,0.0))` implied by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could define two function template **overloads** (when it comes to function templates, *overloading* is usually preferable to *specialization*) called `compute_norm()`, one accepting `std::complex` and one accepting unconstrained types. The unconstrained template would invoke `operator *`, while the constrained template would invoke `std::norm()`.

```
#include <complex>

template<typename T>
double compute_norm(T t)
{ return t * t; }

template<typename T>
double compute_norm(std::complex<T> const& t)
{ return std::norm(t); }
```

Then, your generic code that can work both with a `double` and with a `complex<double>` would call `compute_norm()`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    // ...
    double n = compute_norm(std::forward<T>(t));
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

For instance, the following program:

```
int main()
{
    double a(2.0);
    foo(a);

    std::complex<double> c(2.0, 3.0);
    foo(c);
}
```

Will output:

```
4
13
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24255).

Comment: thanks as well ! but then i still have a method that is specialized and that has to be in a separate .cpp file..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use function overloading?

```
double myNorm(double);
double myNorm(std::complex<double>);


double myNorm(double x) {
    return x * x;
}
double myNorm(std::complex<double> x) {
    return std::norm(x);
}
```

You can put the implementation in your .cpp or (when inlined) in your header file.

Comment: yeah but the std::norm() of a std::complex<double> computes the square of the abs...

Comment: @user2110463 Ok, didn't know that. So it's going to be consistent, removing my warning ;)